# PHPUnit: dataProvider issue

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

What's wrong with the following test:

```
<?php

class TestSomething extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testSomething($array, $expectedResult)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($array, $expectedResult);
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        return array(
            array(array(), array()),
        );
    }
}

?>
```

Error message:

```
$phpunit index.php
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for TestSomething::testSomething() in /var/www/tests/something-test/index.php on line 8
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for TestSomething::testSomething() in /var/www/tests/something-test/index.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: array in /var/www/tests/something-test/index.php on line 11
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: expectedResult in /var/www/tests/something-test/index.php on line 11
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException' with message 'Failed asserting that 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

)
 is equal to <string:testSomething>.' in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php:164
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php(2087): PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual->fail(Array, '')
#1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php(343): PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertThat(Array, Object(PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual), '')
#2 /var/www/tests/something-test/index.php(11): PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals('testSomething', Array)
#3 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(537): TestSomething->testSomething('testSomething', Array, 0)
#4 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(816): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::createTest(Object(ReflectionClass), 'testSomething')
#5 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(224): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestMethod(Object(ReflectionClass), Object(Reflectio in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php on line 164
```

Thanks.

Comment: You sure there aren't any parenthesis/curly braces missing?

Comment: I can't see the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because your test is also being executed as the constructor:

```
class TestSomething extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testSomething($array, $expectedResult)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($array, $expectedResult);
    }

    // ...

}
```

For PHP4 compatibility, you can use the class name as the method name to declare a constructor. It is also done in a case insensitive manner (i.e.: `testSomething()` is considered a constructor to `TestSomething`). Usually, you will append the `Test` keyword to your class name to prevent that from happening (instead of prepending):

```
class SomethingTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch! I looked for a constructor since I know that's how each data set gets passed in but totally forgot about the PHP4 class-name-as-constructor thing.

Comment: Come on! This kind of constructor sucks! :( Thank you. Problem fixed!

Comment: Many other languages use the class's name as the name for the constructor method, e.g. C++ and Java.

Answer (score 13):

I've also just gotten bit by much the same thing, I was using the `__construct()` method to setup internal variables.

What I needed to do instead was have a `function setUp() {}` where that would happen.

---

**I've just fallen over this problem again** - but this time the problem was the comment - I had used:

```
/*
 * @dataProvider ....
 */
```

But the comment has to start with `/**` to be recognised.

Comment: My comment started with: 
   /**+
Major typo... wasted 30 min finding the problem...

Comment: Wow thank you, I was using the `__construct()` just fine forever until I added the dataProvider, then everything blew up and it was a nightmare to troubleshoot. I probably never would have figured this out if it weren't for you, thanks!!

Comment: /* vs /** is a particularly hellish gotcha.

Comment: Tis can be now upgraded instantly with Rector: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/issues/2143

Answer (score 7):

For future-comers arriving here because phpunit ran the data provider function as a test and showed a "risky test" flag with `This test did not perform any assertions`, it seems that since phpunit 6 (maybe 6.3?) phpunit no longer ignores the "test" prefix in the data provider functions, e.g. `testAdditionProvider`. Renaming it to `additionProvider` as in the [current docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) works.
I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP pre-5.3.3:

Are you giving the variables on establishing the class?
Because your class and function name (TestSomething/testSomething) are the same (case-insensitive).
So it sees the function testSomething as as constructor.

Comment: Actually, this behavior still exists in 5.3.3 and up, including 5.4.

Comment: According to the PHP website (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) at Example #2 it should be treated as regular function. But tho, I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I've read it but i'm using PHP 5.3... So, this statement looks wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @thom: It's `__construct` actually.

Comment: @Max 'TheM' Klaversma: You're partially right. *"As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a **namespaced class name** will no longer be treated as constructor."*